# Events plot for arrivals and departures in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have never used Python for visualization and plotting and I was wondeing if there is any way to plot a set of arrivals and theier associated departures using matplotlib (or any other libraies) in Python? I am basicly trying to demo something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. The question is more on if plotting time events is even possible with matplotlib sinece as I mentioned I have never used it. I dont expect anyone to do for me.

Comment: Yes, it's possible via pythons `datetime` objects.